# No consigo evitar el error "'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trato de obtener imágenes en las que los colores más cercanos entre sí por decirlo de alguna forma se vayan sustituyendo para crear una imagen más homogénea. El problema es que no entiendo qué tengo que cambiar para que se arregle mi error, adjunto el código completo con el error en negrita y espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
    def distance(color1,color2):
        result=0
        for i in range(len(color1)):
            result=result+(color1[i]-color2[i])**2
        return result

      def dist1(color1,color2):
        result=0
        for i in range(len(color1)):
            result=result+(color1[i]-color2[i])**2
        return result

      def dist2(color1,color2):
        result=0
        for i in range(len(color1)):
            result=max(result,abs(color1[i]-color2[i]))
        return result

      def dist3(color1,color2):
        result=0
        cofs=[2,4,3]
        for i in range(len(color1)):
            result=result+cofs[i]*(color1[i]-color2[i])**2
        return result

      def muestra(img,k,l):
        width,heigth=img.size
        result=[]
        for x in range(0,width,width//k):
            for y in range(0,heigth,heigth//l):
                result.append(img.getpixel((x,y)))
        return result

     def proximo(color,color_list,distance):
        min=distance(color,color_list[0])
        index_min=0
        for i in range(1,len(color_list)):
            d=distance(color,color_list[i])
            if d<min:
                min=d
                index_min=i
        return index_min

    def prox_subst_inic(img,color_list,distance):
        width,heigth=img.size
        result=Image.new("RGB",(width,heigth),(0,0,0))
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(heigth):
                color=img.getpixel((x,y))
                index=proximo(color,color_list,distance)
                result.putpixel((x,y),color_list[index])
        return result
 def divide_color(color,n):
        return (round(color[0])/n),round(color[1]/n),round(color[2]/n)
        hist= [int] 

    def prox_subst(img,color_list,distance):
        width,height=img.size
        new_color_list=[(0,0,0)*len(color_list)]
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                color=img.getpixel((x,y))
                index=proximo(color,color_list,distance)
                new_color_list[index]=tuple(new_color_list[index]+color(i) for i in range(3))
        return (divide_color[(new_color_list[i], hist[i]) for i in range(len(hist)))]
```

En la penúltima linea aparece el error:

> new_color_list[index]=tuple(new_color_list[index]+color[i] for i in range(3))

Comment: Es dificil leer el código que has pegado porque aparece todo mal indentado. Mira aqui la forma correcta de pegar el código para que se vea bien --> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Ya la he editado,pero sigo sin arreglar el error

Comment: Veo que haces `color=img.getpixel((x,y))`. Seguramente eso te devuelve un entero o una tupla. En todo caso. seguro que no te devuelve una función, y de ahí el error cuando intentas "llamarlo" con `color(i)`, en la línea que mencionas.

Comment: Lo he arreglado para tener una lista con todo los colores,el problema ahora es que el range me da el error "list index out of range" que no se cómo salvarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en la línea anterior a la que marcas `index=proximo(color,color_list,distance)` esto a lo que pude entender deja en index un número. En la siguiente línea ejecutas `index(i)+color(i)` con index como número. Espero sea eso, si indentas tu código sería mucho mejor